# How do I get Email Performance by Device using a Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

How to get Email Performance by Device to populate device name using SQL query in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Hi @AR, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: @Martin Lezer 

how to get the Email Performance by Device using  SQL query

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: manually its possible  but using Query how do i Do this is my query: Select * from _sent  data is coming but device name not coming

Comment: how to get the Email Performance by Device and need to popluate device name using  SQL query In exacttarget

Comment: how to check "OR" condtion in lookup() mean status= open or failed this is my ex: var recordsToSend = DB.lookup(this.syncQueueTable, { Status: "Open" }, "Id DESC");

Answer (score 2):

Some device data is available via Tracking Data Extract, if you check the `Include User Agent Information` option.  It's included in the extract of `Sent` data.

To use it in a Query Activity, you'd need to extract it, and import it back into the platform.

More info here: [**Extract Types Reference**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/)

Comment: i need to get device  data  using  Query Activity

Comment: It's only available for your Query Activity if you import/export it into a Data Extension from a Tracking Extract.  It's not in an out-of-the-box System Data View.

Comment: how to check "OR" condtion in lookup()  mean status= open or failed this is my ex: var recordsToSend = DB.lookup(this.syncQueueTable, { Status: "Open" }, "Id DESC");

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with a Query Activity in Marketing Cloud. 
You can get a custom query activity built by Salesforce for your account

Comment: how can i Write  custom Query

Comment: You can't write it. Salesforce will create a custom data view for your and then you use that

Comment: how to check "OR" condtion in lookup() mean status= open or failed this is my ex: var recordsToSend = DB.lookup(this.syncQueueTable, { Status: "Open" }, "Id DESC");